# Styling jQuery validation

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-validate

When I have this, the div, which just has text in it, uses all the horizontal width it can, so there's trailing width after the text, which I can tell from the background color.

```
    errorElement: "div",
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {

            error.insertBefore("#zzz");
```

When I use this, the width is the same as the text contained, but I cannot get each individual error (span) to be on a separate line via display: block.

```
    errorElement: "span",
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {

            error.insertBefore("#zzz");
            error.css("display", "block");
```

Is there another way to force a break on a span element?

Comment: Why don't you use `<br/>` or `<p>` tags to force line breaks? Could it be your css contains a float? Why are you trying to use a `<span>` (an inline element) for a block-level element? Why not just put each individual error in a `<div>`?

Comment: div works, but when background is red and the text is short, you have a huge block of red following the text.  Tried auto and min width - they don't work.  I want the div to be the same length as the text.  Looking into setting the width based on the type of error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I was confused by what you were looking for, but my comment above stands. Why not use html elements to force a line break rather than trying to shoehorn it into css? If you want each error span on a separate line, wrap it in a `<p>` or add a `<br/>`.

Something like this should work:

```
errorElement: "span",
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.wrap('<p>');
        // alternative:  error.append('<br/>');
        error.insertBefore("#zzz");
```

An `li` element instead of `span` would also be a good choice semantically, as @Victor suggests. (It is a list of errors, after all.) You would also need a `<ul>` enclosing the error section.

Comment: This worked.  I just had to make a minor change, the wrap goes after the insertBefore.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yo can have a `span` with the different background color inside a `div` for the block display.

Also, `<li>`

Comment: I was thinking about that, but I'm not certain how to insert it into the div.  I'm guessing it would be something like InsertInside errorElement span.

Comment: You could do it with `.wrap('<li>')`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.  It's not exactly the best way, but if anyone has anything more maintainable, please let me know.  I'm a bit peeved the display:block didn't work for the span.  Oh well.

```
 errorElement: "div",
 errorPlacement: function(error, element) {

     error.insertBefore("#zzz");      

     if (error.text() == 'Password Required')
     {
          error.css("width", "135px");
     }
     else
     {
          error.css("width", "165px");
     }
```